# Creating and assigning tasks to threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a piece of code here which takes a long time to run. The code basically go through each file in the file list and do stuffs. How do I create 4 threads and let each of them handle one file (since there are only 4 files).

```
public static void run(String referenceFile, String dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    List<Gene> referenceGenes = ParseReferenceGenes(referenceFile);
    List<String> filenames = ListGenbankFiles(dir);
    for (String filename:filenames)
    {
        System.out.println(filename);
        GenbankRecord record = Parse(filename);
        for (Gene referenceGene : referenceGenes)
        {
            System.out.println(referenceGene.name);
            for (Gene gene : record.genes)
            {
                if (Homologous(gene.sequence, referenceGene.sequence)) {
                    NucleotideSequence upStreamRegion = GetUpstreamRegion(record.nucleotides, gene);
                    Match prediction = PredictPromoter(upStreamRegion);
                    if (prediction != null) {
                        consensus.get(referenceGene.name).addMatch(prediction);
                        consensus.get("all").addMatch(prediction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Sigma70Consensus> entry : consensus.entrySet())
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) to create an `ExecutorService`, and use the `execute()` method to start your tasks, or, alternatively [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) when you need to return results.

For example, do something like this:

```
public static void run(String referenceFile, String dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    List<Gene> referenceGenes = ParseReferenceGenes(referenceFile);
    List<String> filenames = ListGenbankFiles(dir);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    List<Callable<Map<String, Sigma70Consensus>>> tasks = ListGenbankFiles(dir);
    for (String filename: filenames)
    {
        tasks.add(new MyTask(filename));
    }
    
    for (Future<Map<String, Sigma70Consensus>> result : executor.invokeAll(tasks)) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Sigma70Consensus> entry : result.get().entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }

}

public class MyTask implements Callable<Map<String, Sigma70Consensus>> {
    private final String fileName;
    public MyTask(String fileName) { this.fileName = fileName; }

    public Map<String, Sigma70Consensus> call() {
        /* The file processing code you have in the loop here */
    }
}
```

If you need a more detailed explanation of this approach, please refer to [this totorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/executorservice-invokeall/)